# Give visitors really quick content edit access w/ email address only, or is there an even simpler way?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-verification

**Background:** I built a website with a team of guys that's kind of like Crunchbase but for another industry. Visitors can add their company, update their company's profile, that kind of stuff. All changes are sent to a backend admin approval panel where admins can verify the accuracy of the changed content before publishing on the site.

**The improvement I need help with:** I want to make it easier for people to be able to edit content. Right now you have to create a username and login, at minimum, to edit content. I would like to allow people to just enter their email address. When they do, we log the email address submitted, associate it with that specific IP address the email was sent from and then send the user and email to verify they are, indeed, the owner of this email. Once they verify, they can begin editing on the site right away and we store a cookie to keep them logged in on that IP address for six-months or so.

They only have to enter their email and re-verify when they moved to a new computer or IP and even in that case, once they verify we can keep them logged in via a cookie for a longer period of time.

Seems like a good solution to making it a simple process.

**Anyone know of anything better or potential problems I could run into with this method? Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: what's to stop someone from using an insecure mail service to generate a few zillion bogus addresses, use each one, and completely trash your site?

Comment: Way too many things wrong with this plan. What Marc said is first, then there are too many people getting dynamic IP's from their service providers that can change daily let alone in 6 months. Make an oAuth login or a quick register just asking for username, email and password, verify the email and be done with it. Every browser has remember my credentials ability. This is going to cause you way more headaches than it's worth to save users the 1 minute it takes to fill out an express register form.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I'll have to rethink this. They won't be able to trash the site because an admin still approves or rejects changes made to the site but still a good point and we don't want all sorts of bogus content entries. What percentage of people are operating with a dynamic IP though, do you think?

Comment: try facebook authentication or openid, with open id all you have to enter is username.openid.com and enter a one time password that stays open for a while.

Answer (score 0):

When a user submits a new profile you could create a random unique string linked to that specific profile then email it to the email they specified. So if they need to edit the content they could simply click the link in their email to edit it. Similar approach to craigslist. However, if their email is compromised the intruder could click that link and change that info as well. You should also setup some kind of brute force detection to keep people from banging in random strings trying to find a good link to mess with content. Good luck!